# Fullcalendar super-thin events (bug with CSS)

Tags: javascript, css, width, fullcalendar

I have a few events in my agenda, but there are displaying like this :

[image: My agenda]

I looked up at CSS, but all seems correct :

- The width of one .fc-event is 43px by instance (inline style) (`position: absolute; z-index: 8; top: 0px; left: 222px; width: 43px; height: 333px;`)
- My website's CSS don't change CSS for divs (and there are only divs)

Do you have any clue ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer myself :

I have a reset.css which set `max-width: 100%` to divs and links, so I added :

`.fc a, .fc div { max-width: none; }` to my CSS and it worked fine.